# No Refresh Button in Firefox URL Bar

Tags: firefox, gui

When running Firefox 10 on a Windows computer, I see a refresh button incorporated into the URL bar at the far right side. However, running in Ubuntu (11.10), I do not:

[image: lacking refresh button on Ubuntu]

However, I see pictures on the Firefox site that show it running on Ubuntu with the button there, so I suspect it is not an OS issue:

[image: refresh button present on Ubuntu]

Might this be because I am using the same Firefox profile I've been using since version, say, 3? How can I get the refresh button *in the URL bar*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *order* of the buttons in the icon bar is important; see the 3rd picture below and notice the exact location. You have to order them like this:

`url-bar` - `reload-button` - `stop-button`

You will end up with standalone buttons if you don't.

To add the reload button to the URL-bar follow these general steps:

1. Right click at the toolbar.

   [image]
2. Click `Customize...`

   [image]
3. Drag the reload button to the toolbar.

   [image]
4. Click `Done`.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer—I already knew how to do that, though. That doesn't give me the refresh button *in the URL bar*. It gives me the regular refresh button.

Comment: @Kazark If the order is *exactly* `Address bar` - `Refresh` - `Stop`, they merge for me in Kubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @Kazark: not if you drag the button to the place where i dragged it in step 3. i checked that in windows and linux, always the same. if you have the reload-button "somewhere" else, it ends up as a separate button.

Answer (score 6):

Drag the Reload & Stop buttons to the toolbar next to the address bar, it'll get merged into the address bar when you come out of customize mode.

With both present:

[image]

Coming out of customize mode, you end up with:

[image]

If the reload button is removed, however

[image]

No integrated reload button:

[image]

Comment: +1 *Coming out of customize mode*—that was part of my problem. As I tried different things, I didn't expect things to change when I switched out from customizing!

Comment: @Kazark heh, that throws off quite a few people :)